# Измерить время выполнения функции в Ruby

Tags: ruby

Банально не могу найти как измерить время выполнения конкретной функции. Я только только делаю первые шаги в Ruby. Подскажите, кто знает. Желательно в микросекундах.

```
def nod(a,b)
  until b===0
    r = a%b
    a=b
    b=r
  end
  a
end
}
def nod_recursion(a,b)
    r = a%b
    a=b
    b=r
    b!=0 ?
      nod_recursion(a,b):
      a
end
a=4_851
b=3_003
print 'Наибольший общий делитель чисел ',a,' и ',b,' равен: ', nod(a,b),"\n"
print 'Наибольший общий делитель чисел методом рекурсии ',a,' и ',b,' равен: ', nod_recursion(a,b),"\n"
```

Хочу уметь сравнивать время выполнения каждой функции. Эти примеры, конечно, примитивны, и скорее всего разницы во времени практически не будет, но тем не менее. И именно поэтому нужно время в микросекундах, думается миллисекунды будут слишком для этой задачи велики.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Специально для этих целей существует [модуль `Benchmark`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html), самый простейший способ измерения в котором это метод `measure`.

Он возвращает объект, содержащий в себе несколько показателей времени, вас скорее всего интересует "прошедшее реальное время", возвращаемое методом `real`.

Время выводится в секундах, но с дробной частью.

```
require 'benchmark'

nod_bench     = Benchmark.measure { nod(a, b) }
nod_rec_bench = Benchmark.measure { nod_recursion(a, b) }

puts "Iterative: #{nod_bench.real}s"
puts "Recursive: #{nod_rec_bench.real}s"
```

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/GpP4/1.js"></script>
```

**Сюрпри-и-из!** Рекурсивная реализация *в тестах* быстрее! Догадаетесь, почему? `:)`

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду тестить! Нет, пока не догадываюсь, а почему?? Я думал наоборот цикл быстрее...

Comment: @Igor в любых синтетических тестах важно отвечать на вопрос: в реализации проблема или в тестах... Но подсказку дам. Поменяйте измерения местами. Измерьте сначала рекурсивную.

Comment: xм... И в правду показывает, что первая функция работает дольше. Ради интереса я создал 5 одинаковых функций и измерял время. и Всегда показывает, что первая дольше всех выполняется, а последняя быстрее всех. В чем же подстава? Как измерять время адекватно? Что можно почитать на эту тему? @D-side

Comment: @Igor правильный подход! Вы выяснили, что первый запуск всегда даёт не вполне адекватные результаты. Напрашивается вывод -- можно совершить этот запуск самостоятельно, чтобы устранить этот эффект, а измерения совершать уже после него. На самом деле явление очень частое, и этот способ устранения называется "разогрев" (warmup), и выполняется обычно для каждого проверяемого участка кода. Но MRI (Ruby VM) в данном случае достаточно вызова любого из методов для разогрева их всех. Необходимость в этом вытекает из наличия кэша и оптимизации кода в VM уже во время выполнения.

Comment: Павел, @D-side (почему-то ссылку на Вас съедает, если ставлю вначале сообщения) вот это глубина познания! Откуда это знаете? Точно, так и есть, вызвал функцию перед измерением и время показывает примерно одинаковое, +- от раза к разу! Посоветуйте, какую-нибудь литературу, хочу тоже стать спецом в этом деле. И в каких языках еще наблюдается такое явление разогрева? В JavaScript, я такого не наблюдал, ну там, похоже и механизм другой. Там с помощью:           
`var runTimeNod = performance.now();
runTimeNod = performance.now() - runTimeNod;`

Comment: Павел, @D-side, а вот еще я заметил особенность. Я измерил не время выполнения, а время создания функции. В смысле объявление функции заключил в метод измерения времени. Так вот первая всегда дольше создается. Ради интереса я "создал" еще 5 функций и вот в чем особенность. Если я просто их создаю и могу даже каждую вызвать, это не повлияет на измеряемое время. А если измерю время создания каждой, то последние будут создаваться быстрее всех. Так что, в этом случае получается, что на разогрев влияет именно измерение времени, в отличие от времени выполнения, когда достаточно вызвать функцию перед

Comment: @Igor я такой прикол впервые увидел в Java, там для точности бенчмарков надо ещё и не один раз запустить. Факт, что в JVM использовалась JIT-компиляция, тогда был у всех на слуху, как и то, что делается это для особо "горячих" (часто проходимых) участков кода. Поэтому то, что по коду надо "пройтись" перед сколько-нибудь практическими замерами, казался самим собой разумеющимся. Оказалось, что во многих языках с VM есть такой эффект. [В JavaScript, говорят, тоже.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28616283/2076787) Но я не сталкивался. Не пишу на JS.

Comment: @Igor а упоминание съедается, потому что это и так мой ответ, а кроме вас тут никого нет, так что я единственный возможный адресат :)